# how to do calculation inside for loop in django template

Tags: python, django

I have to do some calculation in django template inside for loop, but it it is not parsing python code inside for loop and giving error

```
{% for ticket in tickets_in_cart %}
    <div class="davis-date-time">
        <h3>{{ ticket.performance_id__event_start_date|date:"M d" }}</h3>
        <p>{{ ticket.performance_id__timing }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="davis-date-time">
      <h3>{{ ticket.performance_id__city }}</h3>
      <p>{{ ticket.performance_id__venue }}</p>
    </div>
    {% singleAmount = ticket.tickets_count*ticket.tickets_amount %}
    {% finalAmount += singleAmount %}

{% endfor %}
```

I have to do this because i need to print this finalAmount variable value outside of the for loop.

Comment: Thats because its not python.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's not "parsing python code" - it's a specific template language, not Python. And a template is not the place for doing calculations, you should be doing all calculations in your models or view and pass the results to your template.

In this case the simplest solution would be to:

1/ make the `ticket` object compute it's own total amount (nb : I assume it's a `Model` class):

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    # fields here

    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.tickets_count * self.tickets_amount
```

2/ Then have a simple "cart" object that holds a list of tickets and knows how to compute the total:

```
class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, tickets):
        self.tickets = tickets

    @property
    def total(self):
        return sum(ticket.total for ticket in self.tickets)
```

And now you just have to instanciate a `Cart` with it's list (or queryset fwiw) of tickets and pass it to your template - not a single computation in your template code, only presentation, problem solved.